# Haproxy Appending Port to `HTTP_HOST` Header in Backend Request

Tags: http, https, url-rewriting, haproxy

I am using *haproxy* in front of my web-server for *ssl* termination.

I am forwarding request on port *81* if request is *http**s*** and *80* if request is normal *http*-

```
backend b1_http
    mode http
    server bkend_server


backend b1_https
    mode http
    server bkend_server:81
```

Problem is, when *haproxy* sends request to back-end, it sends *HTTP_HOST* header as `request.domain.com:81`.

Is it possible in *haproxy* that I can send *https* request to back-end at specific port without appending the port in *HTTP_HOST* request header?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues, here.

First, there is no `HTTP_HOST` header.  The header is `Host:`.  It sounds like `HTTP_HOST` is something being generated internally by your web server or framework.

Second, HAProxy doesn't modify the `Host:` header just because your back-end is listening on a port other than 80.  It doesn't actually modify the `Host:` header at all, unless explicit configured to, using a mechanism like `reqirep ^Host: ...` or `http-request set-header host ...`.

You can confirm this with a packet capture.  You should find that whatever `HTTP_HOST` is, the value is necessarily being generated internally on the back-end system itself, because it's not coming from HAProxy.

Comment: Thanks, you were correct. There is nothing like HTTP_HOST header sent by haproxy, it was internal.

Comment: But when the request is sent to some backend like `bkend_server:123`, the http request received at backend was `abc.domain.com:123`, [i understand it's standard convention (host:port) to send request]  which earlier with elb was `abc.domain.com`, if backend port was 123 or any port. I wasn't doing any explicit configuration. What else can be the cause that it behaving in that way.  =====. 
I've logged request in IIS under `cs-host` was like `abc.domain.com:port` when request was passed via haproxy and `abc.domain.com` when passed via elastic loadbalancer.

Comment: The *browser* should append the port to the hostname, but only when it is not :80 for http or not :443 for https.  I have never seen ELB nor HAProxy autonomously append a port number, regardless of the actual back-end port.  Was ELB hitting 81 just like HAProxy?

Comment: I was also surprised to see this behavior, i wasn't expecting it either. Both elb and haproxy are hitting 81 port, but request via haproxy hits IIS as `ab.domain.com:81` and via ELB as 'abc.domain.com`

Comment: What version of HAProxy?  What web server is on the back-end? What port is the front-end listening on (443 I assume)?

Comment: It's HAProxy 1.6, it's backend IIS behind ELB and yes frontend is listening on 443.